# Inequality Comparison Operator in VB?

Tags: vb.net

In C I write an `if` statement like:

`if (a != 0)`

How do I write this `!=` operator in VB?

Answer (score 6):

```
if a <> 0 then
  ' code
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

another way :)

```
    Dim a As Integer = 3
    If Not (a = 0) Then
        Console.WriteLine("is not equal")
    End If
```

Comment: i have a broblem i want to delete list box but it getting out when the val is "0" how can i write that it will remove until the listbox will be empty

Comment: Private Sub ListBox1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DoubleClick
        Dim fish, dvash, shipod, kalamar, shrim As String


        fish = "fish"
        dvash = "dvash"
        shipod = "shipod"
        kalamar = "kalamar"
        shrim = "shrim"
        If ListBox1.Items = fish Or dvash Or shipod Or kalamar Or shrim Then
            ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)


        End If